# What is Struts .struts.mex file

Tags: java, struts

I am new in Struts. I have got an existing java project in struts. the project has struts.xml and .struts.mex file. 
I understood that struts.xml is the action class to action mapping and the respective jsps in the success and error scenario.

But not able to understand why the .struts.mex file is used? Is it part of struts? Any information?

Comment: What is the IDE you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research i think that it is a file created automatically by the [struts editor](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/web/struts-editor-myeclipse/) of the [MyEclipse IDE](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/).
MyEclipse is a custom proprietary version of Eclipse by [Genuitec](https://www.genuitec.com/).

[Here's](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/struts-config-mex-and-cvs/) a post on Genuitec's forum that confirm what i said.

If you, or someone else, is using this IDE to develop the project, i advice you don't delete that file.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not part of Struts. AFAIK it's one of two things:

- JSF-ish model flow diagram/relationship diagram
- Matlab file